# In C++ is it possible to link to a .lib file that was compiled with earlier version of Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I have a project that we are looking to port from Visual studio 6 to Visual Studio 2010.

The project relies on a 3rd party .LIB file that is pre-compiled. This 3rd party library only contains the .H header files (no .CPP files)

I have just done a quick imprt into a visual studio 2010 solution and I am getting lots of errors at link time!

Some of these errors refer to the 3rd party .lib file "ServerToolkitRuntimeLIB.LIB"

Here is small snippit from the output of my build:

```
1>ServerToolkitRuntimeLIB.LIB(SerialIO.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void  __cdecl std::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@std@@YAXXZ)
1>ServerToolkitRuntimeLIB.LIB(OPCConversions.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@std@@YAXXZ)
1>ServerToolkitRuntimeLIB.LIB(OPCMemoryAS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@std@@YAXXZ)
1>ServerToolkitRuntimeLIB.LIB(OPCAddressSpace.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@std@@YAXXZ)
1>ServerToolkitRuntimeLIB.LIB(OPCServer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@std@@YAXXZ)
```

Am I at a loose end here without the source to rebuild the 3rd party library or could there be something else going on here?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: The 3rd party .lib was originally compiled in Visual Studio 6.0

Comment: Are the 3rd party .lib files pre-compiled with VC++ 6.0 or other versions?

Comment: Yes they are pre-compiled with VC++ 6.0. Sorry, I should of mentioned that!

Comment: I am using libraries that were compiled for VC2008 in VC2010 with no problems. The library and the projects must be compiled with the same configuration (flags) to be compatible.

Comment: interesting. Because I simply upgraded the old .dsw (vc6 project) straight to the new vc2010 .sln project I believe my configuration should still be compatible. Bear in mind I can compile this project just fine in vc6. Its definatly left me stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have VS6 you could try to produce a DLL there, linking to that .lib file you have, and exporting the necessary symbols.

Then you could link that dll dynamically in your VS 2010 project without using the .lib

Comment: Hmm. An interesting approach... If I am understanding you correctly would that mean I would need to write the function signitures in the .dll for all of the classes in the .lib. to forward the calls to. Just looking at the library header files it has 76 objects with lots of public functions!

Comment: Yup. I think that would be a solution with a good control over the results. You can do it incrementally - try wrapping or exposing a single symbol, and then check if you can load and use it in VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd party library depend on some internal implementation of VS6 that removed from VS2010, so normally you can't use it without the source, but there is a tricky way of using it.

Usually this implementation functions are all open source in VS6, you can see its implementation and implement your own version and link against it, if simple link does not solve the problem you should compile your implementations as a separate DLL and link against it!

Comment: I see. I take it "tricky" being the operative word there! :)  Have you got any reference material you can refer me to?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I'm not a native English speaker. But about reference for more information I have to say there is no such a reference since referenced functions are all internal functions that use for implementation you should understand them from source of CRT in VC6. for example `std::_Xlen` that mentioned in your question will throw an exception and will be used by some STL containers like `std::string` to indicate an error